# zpool mirror-0 is missing and disks are showing separately

Tags: linux, zfs

I am new to zfs and zpool. I see zpool mirror-0 is missing and disks sbd and sdc are showing separately. How do I fix this? When we import or export zpool, where is it getting imported from or exported to?

```
  pool: sanpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 4.98G in 0h46m with 0 errors on Fri Mar 12 04:45:32 2021
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    sanpool     ONLINE       0     0     0
      sdc       ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdh     ONLINE       0     0     0
      sdb       ONLINE       0     0     0
    spares
      sdg       AVAIL
```

Comment: What is the output for the pool supposed to look like?  `sdb` and `sdc` in `mirror-0`?

Comment: Was this pool actually created with sdb and sdc as part of a mirror vdev?  Please edit your question and add the output of `zpool history sanpool | grep zpool.create`.   If the pool was created with those drives in a mirror vdev then something has seriously corrupted the pool.  Either way, your only option is to re-create the pool and restore from backup (if you don't have a backup, try to backup as much of the data on the pool as you can...and remember in future that neither raid nor zfs is a substitute for backup)

Comment: actually, if you made a mistake when first creating the pool and it **wasn't** made with sdb & sdc in a mirror vdev, another option is to add two new drives to the pool - one as a mirror for sdb and the other as a mirror for sdc.   This will correct the original mistake and add the redundancy to the pool.

Comment: Yes, sdb and sdc were in mirror-0. sdb got faulty, instead of replacing it with spare I removed it and that removed the mirror. Had to recreate the pool to fix it but is that the only option?

Comment: my guess is that when you added a replacement for sdb, you added it as a single-drive vdev with 'zpool add` rather than attaching it to sdc with `zpool attach` (which would have turned the single-drive sdc vdev back into a mirror vdev).   See `man zpool` and search for "zpool add" and "zpool attach" (in recent versions of ZoL, these have their own individual man pages, so use `man zpool-add` and `man zpool-attach`)

Comment: the key thing to remember here is that `zpool add` adds a vdev to a pool - and that vdev can be a single drive, a mirror, a raid-z. `zpool add` is also used to add cache or log devices to a pool.    `zpool attach`, OTOH, attaches a new device to an existing single-drive or mirror vdev, turning it into a mirror (or changing it from a 2-way mirror to 3-way, or 3-way to 4-way, etc).

Comment: If you've accidentally **added** a drive to a pool instead of **attaching** it, the only way to fix it (apart from re-creating the pool and restoring from backup) is to attach another drive to it so it becomes a mirror vdev instead of a single-drive vdev.